# switch\case not working as expected

Tags: android, switch-statement

My Log line says animalclass is 4 but instead of going to "case 4" it returns default. It works with case 2 though. How is this possible? Thanks in advance.

```
public int gettile(int animalclass) {
    Log.e("gettile", "animalclass = " + animalclass); 
    switch (animalclass) {
    case 1: // 
        tile=R.drawable.picnictile; 

        break;

    case 2: // 

        tile=R.drawable.picnictile; 

        break;

    case 3: // 

        tile=R.drawable.picnictile; 

    case 4: // 

        tile=R.drawable.picnictile; 

    case 5: // 

        tile=R.drawable.face; 


    default:
        Log.e("gettile", "failed!!!!!!!!!! = " + animalclass); 
        tile=R.drawable.rainbowtile;    

        break;
    }
    Log.e("gettile", "returning = " + tile); 
    return tile;
}
```

Comment: Excuse me while I wipe this egg off my face.........Thanks guys.

Comment: you're welcome. Just mark this Question as answered :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `break;` to stop other case execution because without break it will execute the correct case block statements and also "default" code block

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the Break statemenet after all cases.

```
case 3: // 
tile=R.drawable.picnictile; 
break;
case 4: // 
tile=R.drawable.picnictile; 
break;
case 5: // 
tile=R.drawable.face; 
break;
```

If you dont break it after the "thing" the case should do, the switch does not work correct.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add a `break` keyword before the `default` keyword.
Try this one:

```
public int gettile(int animalclass) {
    Log.e("gettile", "animalclass = " + animalclass); 
    switch (animalclass) {
    case 1: // 
        tile=R.drawable.picnictile; 

        break;

    case 2: // 

        tile=R.drawable.picnictile; 

        break;

    case 3: // 

        tile=R.drawable.picnictile; 
    break;
    case 4: // 

        tile=R.drawable.picnictile; 
    break;
    case 5: // 

        tile=R.drawable.face; 

    break;
    default:
        Log.e("gettile", "failed!!!!!!!!!! = " + animalclass); 
        tile=R.drawable.rainbowtile;    

        break;
    }
    Log.e("gettile", "returning = " + tile); 
    return tile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **break;** keyword after each case, otherwise switch will execute **default** statement also and result will be unexpected.